# plm: Fixed Effects Regression - Index / ID order

Tags: r, regression, plm

I am running fixed effects regressions using the `plm` package.
Why and how does the order of the ID code have an impact on the regression?

I used these codes for running the regressions, which only differ between the order of the ID code `Company` and `Year`.

The code:

```
MV_Year <- plm (MVlog ~ LEV + Size + DY + RDlog
                , data=Values, model="within", index= c("Year","Company"))


MV_Company <- plm (MVlog ~ LEV + Size + DY + RDlog,
                   data=Values, model="within", index= c("Company", "Year"))
```

The corresponding outputs:
MV_Year:

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = MVlog ~ LEV + Size + DY + RDlog, data = Values, 
    model = "within", index = c("Year", "Company"))

Unbalanced Panel: n = 17, T = 557-4280, N = 29890

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-5.250901 -0.457100  0.015763  0.476140  6.006483 

Coefficients:
         Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
LEV   -1.95485031  0.04060539 -48.143  < 2e-16 ***
Size   0.75233709  0.00314849 238.952  < 2e-16 ***
DY    -0.00033192  0.00013482  -2.462  0.01382 *  
RDlog  0.13148626  0.00300509  43.755  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    102610
Residual Sum of Squares: 17568
R-Squared:      0.82879
Adj. R-Squared: 0.82868
F-statistic: 36148 on 4 and 29869 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

MV_Company

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = MVlog ~ LEV + Size + DY + RDlog, data = Values, 
    model = "within", index = c("Company", "Year"))

Unbalanced Panel: n = 5911, T = 1-17, N = 29890

Residuals:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-4.35967 -0.38711  0.00000  0.40528  5.48624 

Coefficients:
         Estimate  Std. Error  t-value Pr(>|t|)    
LEV   -1.88958140  0.04392991 -43.0135  < 2e-16 ***
Size   0.74650676  0.00375926 198.5782  < 2e-16 ***
DY    -0.00034308  0.00014585  -2.3524  0.01866 *  
RDlog  0.13904360  0.00331886  41.8950  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    58168
Residual Sum of Squares: 12747
R-Squared:      0.78085
Adj. R-Squared: 0.72679
F-statistic: 21356.2 on 4 and 23975 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Why do the outputs have these small differences between the different estimates and R^2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the `index=` option is that `plm()` internally uses `pdata.frame()` which expects the first column to be the `"id"` and the second column to be the `"time"` if the according names are not specified by `index=(<id>, <time>)`

From `?pdata.frame` we can read:

> The index argument indicates the dimensions of the panel. It can be:
>
> - a vector of two character strings which contains the names of the individual and of the time indexes,
> - a character string which is the name of the individual index variable. In this case,  the time index is created automatically and
>     a new variable called "time" is added, assuming consecutive and
>     ascending time periods in the order of the original data, ...

The following example will help us to understand this. First we load the `Grunfeld` data, which looks like this.

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld)
head(Grunfeld, 3)
#   firm year   inv  value capital
# 1    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
# 2    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
# 3    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9
```

First column is the ID, second column is the time. Let's estimate a model.

```
summary(plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld,
            model="within"))$coe
#          Estimate Std. Error   t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1101238 0.01185669  9.287901 3.921108e-17
# capital 0.3100653 0.01735450 17.866564 2.220007e-42
```

Now, when we confuse the first and the second column,

```
summary(plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld[c(2, 1, 3:5)],
            model="within"))$coe
#          Estimate  Std. Error   t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1167978 0.006331302 18.447672 3.586220e-43
# capital 0.2197066 0.032296107  6.802881 1.503653e-10
```

the result is different. But when we tell `plm` by `index=(<id>, <time>)` which columns to use,

```
summary(plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld[c(2, 1, 3:5)], 
            index=c("firm", "year"),
            model="within"))$coe
#          Estimate Std. Error   t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1101238 0.01185669  9.287901 3.921108e-17
# capital 0.3100653 0.01735450 17.866564 2.220007e-42
```

we get the old result. If we confuse the columns completely,

```
summary(plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld[c(3:5, 1, 2)],
            model="within"))$coe
# Error
```

`plm()` is indeed confused :) But jus as before, when we help `plm()` it behaves as expected and yields again the **right** result.

```
summary(plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld[c(3:5, 1, 2)], 
            index=c("firm", "year"),
            model="within"))$coe
#          Estimate Std. Error   t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1101238 0.01185669  9.287901 3.921108e-17
# capital 0.3100653 0.01735450 17.866564 2.220007e-42
```

**Notice,** that you are actually just calculating company fixed effects. If you intend to calculate a model with firm and year fixed effects, let's do this  as a LSDV model,

```
summary(lm(inv ~ value + capital + factor(firm) + factor(year) - 1, Grunfeld))$coe[1:2, ]
#          Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1177159 0.01375128  8.560354 6.652575e-15
# capital 0.3579163 0.02271901 15.754043 5.453066e-35
```

we see that the values are different from above, because the `plm`s just included the firm fixed effect so far, see:

```
summary(lm(inv ~ value + capital + factor(firm) - 1, Grunfeld))$coe[1:2, ]
#          Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1101238 0.01185669  9.287901 3.921108e-17
# capital 0.3100653 0.01735450 17.866564 2.220007e-42
```

To get it right, we then also need to specify `effect="twoways"` to get firm and year fixed effects.

```
summary(plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld,
            index=c("firm", "year"),
            model="within", effect="twoways"))$coe
#          Estimate Std. Error   t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1177159 0.01375128  8.560354 6.652575e-15
# capital 0.3579163 0.02271901 15.754043 5.453066e-35
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your full and informative answer and thank you for including an example!