# How to turn year fixed-effects into decade fixed-effects with plm()?

Tags: r, regression, aggregate, panel, plm

For my bachelor thesis I have a regression with fixed-effects and time-fixed effects in years:

> log⁡(production_it )= β_0 + β_1 * log⁡(temp_it ) + β_2 * log⁡(rain_it
> ) + β_3 * drought_it + β_4 * flood_it + β_5 * storm_it + β_6 *
> log⁡(labour_it )+ β_7* log⁡(Fertilitzer_it )+ β_8* log⁡(capital_it )+
> β_9* log⁡(area_it )+ η_t+ u_i+ ε_it

where

> i: country, t: year

```
r1.time.fixed <- plm(log(production) ~ log(temp) + log(rain) + drought + flood + 
                       storm + log(labour) + log(fertilizer) + log(capital) +
                       log(area), data=pm.rich, model="within", effect="twoways")
```

Now I want to create the following regression with decade instead of year as fixed-effect:

> log⁡(production_id )= β_0 + β_1 * log⁡(temp_id ) + β_2 * log⁡(rain_id
> ) + β_3 * drought_id + β_4 * flood_id + β_5 * storm_id + β_6 *
> log⁡(labour_id )+ β_7* log⁡(Fertilitzer_id )+ β_8* log⁡(capital_id )+
> β_9* log⁡(area_id )+ η_d+ u_i+ ε_id

where

> i:country, d: decade

How can I create the decade fixed-effects in r, given a panel data set based on year data?

Here you can find my data I use:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you want the averages for each country in each decade as single observations, where you probably want the `mean` values for each country in each decade. We do this outside `plm` using `aggregate`, where we `paste0` together the first three `substr`ings of the years with a zero, e.g. 193<strike>5</strike> → 1930. Let me show you with the `Grunfeld` data that comes with `plm`:

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld)
Grunfeld <- transform(Grunfeld, decade=paste0(substr(year, 1, 3), "0"))
head(Grunfeld, 3)
#   firm year   inv  value capital decade
# 1    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8   1930
# 2    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6   1930
# 3    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9   1930
dim(Grunfeld)
# [1] 200   6
```

This allows us to `aggregate` along the decades:

```
Grunfeld.a <- aggregate(. ~ firm + decade, Grunfeld, mean)
head(Grunfeld.a, 3)
#   firm decade year    inv   value capital
# 1    1   1930 1937 341.70 4046.54  124.98
# 2    2   1930 1937 305.56 1921.00  159.06
# 3    3   1930 1937  49.60 2057.12  129.80
dim(Grunfeld.a)
# [1] 30  6
```

Now we could just put the aggregated `Grunfeld.a` into the original `plm` call, since `plm` internally does some "magic" to recognize the *unit* and *time* variables. However, I consider that as dangerous and recommend to explicitly state the `index=`es in the `plm` call (see an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667655/6574038) of mine for a comprehensive explanation):

```
## unit and year FE
fit.year <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld, index=c("firm", "year"), 
                model="within", effect="twoways")

## unit and decade FE
fit.decade <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld.a, index=c("firm", "decade"), 
                model="within", effect="twoways")
```

For the statistical summary you may want to use robust standard errors clustered by unit (i.e. by *country* in your case, or *firm* in this example). `plm` comes with a `summary.plm` method that allows to customize the `vcov=` using `vcovHC.plm`. Note that `cluster=c("group")` confusingly means that you want to cluster by the variable you defined as *unit* variable, (i.e. country in your case). For the estimation `type=` we might want to use `"HC3"` as it is standard in the [`sandwich`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/index.html) package and often recommended today.

```
## unit and year FE
summary(fit.year, vcov=vcovHC(fit.year, type="HC3", cluster=c("group")))$coe
#          Estimate Std. Error t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1177159 0.01212638 9.70742 5.539985e-18
# capital 0.3579163 0.05915972 6.05000 9.049182e-09

## unit and decade FE
summary(fit.decade, vcov=vcovHC(fit.decade, type="HC3", cluster=c("group")))$coe
#          Estimate Std. Error  t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# value   0.1541480 0.05601229 2.752039 1.417452e-02
# capital 0.3476384 0.06517729 5.333735 6.719637e-05
```